# I am having a difficult time updating my react state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, input, slider

I'm just getting back into react and I'm trying to update these inputs that are made dynamically. The last thing that I am stuck on is updating the hooks so I can use the information for later. But when a change has occurred, it updates late, for example I flip the slider from 4 to 5 but ratingValue = 4, now if I then go to 4 from 5, ratingValue = 5.[image: code exmaple]

[image: code example]

Here is my app.js

```
function App() {

  const [ratingValue, setRatingValue] = useState({});
  const [reviewValue, setReviewValue] = useState('');

  function applyFill(slider, id) {
    setRatingValue((prevState)=>({...prevState, [id]: slider.value }))
    console.log(ratingValue[id])
    const percentage = (100 * (slider.value - slider.min)) / (slider.max - slider.min);
    const bg2 = `linear-gradient(90deg, #CF31B6, #FF0000 ${percentage}%, lightgrey ${percentage +
      0.1}%)`;
      slider.style.background = bg2;

    switch(slider.value) {
      case '1':
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('#slider').style.setProperty("--SliderImage", "url('image')");
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('.rating').innerText = 'Unlikely to wear';
        
        break;
      case '2':
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('#slider').style.setProperty('--SliderImage', "url('image')")
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('.rating').innerText = 'Need to be convinced to wear';
       
        break;
      case '3':
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('#slider').style.setProperty('--SliderImage', "url('image')")
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('.rating').innerText = 'Likely to wear';
        
        break;
      case '4':
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('#slider').style.setProperty('--SliderImage', "url('image')")
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('.rating').innerText = 'Definitely will wear';
        
        break;
      case '5':
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('#slider').style.setProperty('--SliderImage', "url('image')")
        slider.parentNode.querySelector('.rating').innerText = 'Love it, will wear often';
      
        break;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(ratingValue)
    }, 1000)
  }

  
  const data = [
    { brand: "Undefeated",
      clothing: "Hoodie",
      id: 1,
    },
    { brand: "Test",
      clothing: "Test",
      id: 2,
    },
  ];

useEffect(() => {
  data.map(e => {
    setRatingValue((prevState)=>({...prevState, [e.id]: '3' }))
  })


const slider = document.querySelectorAll(".range__slider");
      slider.forEach(item => {
        item.querySelector('input').value = '3'
        applyFill(item.querySelector('input'), item.querySelector('input').parentNode.id)
      });
      
    }, [])
    

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Button className="btn btn-dark position-absolute back-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} className="me-2" />Back</Button>
      <h1 className='mt-5'>Rate & Review</h1>
      <p>We would love to hear your thoughts! Please note, you may only write one review per product. Reviews cannot be edited once submitted</p>
   
    {/* item card */}
      {data.map((e) => (
        <ItemCard applyFill={applyFill} brand={e.brand} clothing={e.clothing} key={e.id} id={e.id} ratingValue={ratingValue} setRatingValue={setRatingValue} reviewValue={reviewValue} setReviewValue={setReviewValue} />
      ))}
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is what is creating the slider:

```
function ItemCard({applyFill, brand, clothing, id, reviewValue, setReviewValue, ratingValue, setRatingValue}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="length range__slider" id={id} data-min="1" data-max="5">

        <div className='d-flex flex-row mb-3 w-100 mt-2'>
          <img className='type-img my-auto mx-3' src={require('./img/hoodie 9.png')} />
          <div>
            <p className="brand text-light mb-0">{brand}</p>
            <p className="type text-light mb-0">{clothing}</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value={ratingValue[id] || '3'} onChange={e => {
          applyFill(e.target, id)
          }} />

        <p className='rating text-light mb-0' >Unlikely to wear</p>
        <textarea className='review mt-3' rows="1" placeholder='Write a review' value={reviewValue} onChange={e => setReviewValue(e.target.value)}></textarea>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

What do I need to change to update my useState to the correct value when I change the input value?

Comment: First thing when your initializing the state it is an array, but on setRatingValue your converting it into object.

Comment: Also while updating state use callback for eg:- setRatingValue((prevState)=>({...prevState,  [id]: slider.value }))

Comment: I've made those two changes, but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Since the setState in react is async you will get the same `ratingValue` in that particular instance. your update state will reflect in console on next render

for eg: just move your console.log() outside the `applyFill`

for refrence: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/



I hope this help you

Comment: @Ronak thank you, that did help. Didn't now about that till now